# How do I target the second instance of a nuxt component within a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to do so, to be able to dynamically bind a class to a DOM element within the second instance of the same Nuxt component.

---

index.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="block in page.fields.blocks">
      <Block v-if="block.fields.style === 'Block'"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Block.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="block" v-bind:class="ifThisIsASecondInstance ? 'left' : 'right'">
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I target the second instance of a nuxt component within a v-for
>   loop?

i will tell you exactly how to do this

**index.vue**

```
<div 
    v-for="(block,index) in page.fields.blocks" 
    :key="block.id">

    <Block 
        v-if="block.fields.style === 'Block'" 
        :index="index"/>
</div>
```

i will assume this is the information present in `page.field.blocks`

```
page :  {
    fields : {
        blocks : [
            {id:"a1", name:"mars",    fields : {style : "Block"}}, //index 0
            {id:"a2", name:"jupiter", fields : {style : "Block"}}, //index 1
            {id:"a3", name:"saturn",  fields : {style : "Block"}}, //index 2
            {id:"a4", name:"uranus",  fields : {style : "Block"}}, //index 3
            {id:"a5", name:"neptune", fields : {style : "Block"}}  //index 4
        ]
   }
}
```

the `index` object in `v-for="(block,index)` will contain the order of elements in the array `page.field.blocks`

- For your usecase, we need to make use of this `index` object
- `index` object needs to be passed to child component i.e **Block.vue**  `:index="index"`
- This `index` object is received in `Block.vue` using `props`

**Block.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <div>block.vue</div> 
      <div :class="index == 1 ? 'left' : 'right'">{{index}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props:["index"]
}
</script>
```

Your goal is to check specifically for second element. check if `index == 1` and assign the appropriate class `:class="index == 1 ? 'left' : 'right'"`

**Update:**

i seemed to have missed a `simple logic` as Highlighted by **@Morty Choi** . 
all below code changes should be done in `index.vue`

create a computed property to filter the objects with `style === 'Block'` before hand

```
computed:{
      filterBlocks(){
        return this.page.fields.blocks.filter((data) => data.fields.style === 'Block');
      }
}
```

and then use the computed property `v-for` in `index.vue`

```
<div 
    v-for="(block,index) in filterBlocks" 
    :key="block.id">
```

Comment: Your solution the `index` is the data index not the `visual index`. You need to filter the blocks first.

Comment: @MortyChoi index will have the order in which element will be rendered in UI. That is enough to detect the second element.

Comment: the outer loop is `v-for="(block,index) in page.fields.blocks" `, inner condition is `v-if="block.fields.style === 'Block'" `. If the index 0 and 1 block `block.fields.style !== 'Block`. The the 2nd instance Block component index will be 3.

Comment: Look at my answer above, You need to filter the page.fields.blocks before hand to ensure the `index` is the actual render index not the data index

Comment: @MortyChoi if index 0 and 1 block block.fields.style !== 'Block' then according to the code i posted in the answer, the <Block .... /> component will not render . Your answer doesn't reflect exactly what the user is looking for. Take a look at the original question.

Comment: the user said `ifThisIsASecondInstance` I think this refer to the 2nd rendered instance not the 2nd data. You are passing the data index and making decision base on it.

Comment: @MortyChoi i will pass the data index only if block.fields.style == 'Block' .  if block.fields.style !== 'Block'  then <Block .... /> will not be rendered in the screen.

Comment: @MortyChoi you are changing the flow which the user posted in the question. i did not change the flow.

Comment: Consider `{id:"a1", name:"mars",    fields : {style : "NoBlock"}}, //index 0`. Then the` index 0` will not rendered and `index 1` will be the first rendered instance. And your code will bind the `left` style to it. But in this case the `index 1` is the first instance.

Comment: @MortyChoi i was stuck in my own zone. sorry. updated the answer

Comment: @MortyChoi thanks for sticking up till my brain start to work :)

Comment: I shall give concert example in the first place

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be solved by using css.

```
div > .Block:nth-child(2) {
    // style definition
}
```

Another way would be bind the class in the outer loop instead.

```
filteredPageFieldsBlocks = page.fields.blocks.filter(b => block.fields.style === 'Block')

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(block, index) in filteredPageFieldsBlocks">
      <Block :class="index === 1 ? 'left' : 'right'"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```